# How to use wget --convert-links

Tags: unix, localhost, wget

I'm using the following command on a site I'm building on my local machine:

```
wget --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --no-parent http://daosawan.dev
```

I'm using MAMP Pro to serve the pages locally. The URL `http://daosawan.dev` points to a directory on my local machine: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/daosawan/

Here's the header of the resulting /index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<title>Daosawan</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="wp-content/themes/daosawan_theme/style.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='q-a-plus-css'  href='wp-content/plugins/q-and-a/css/q-a-plus.css@ver=1.0.6.2.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://daosawan.dev/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://daosawan.dev/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/daosawan_theme/js/daosawan.js@ver=3.8.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://daosawan.dev/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://daosawan.dev/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.8.1" />
<!-- Q & A -->
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-content/plugins/q-and-a/css/q-a-plus-noscript.css@ver=1.0.6.2.css" /></noscript><!-- Q & A -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.qtrans_flag span { display:none }
.qtrans_flag { height:12px; width:18px; display:block }
.qtrans_flag_and_text { padding-left:20px }
.qtrans_flag_en { background:url(wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/flags/gb.png) no-repeat }
.qtrans_flag_fr { background:url(wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/flags/fr.png) no-repeat }
</style>
<link hreflang="fr" href="http://daosawan.dev/fr/" rel="alternate" />
</head>
```

Notice how some of the `<link>` and `<script>` tags are converted to relative, but some keep the `http://`, and breaks when I try to publish the saved website/page to a public location.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that certain absolute URLs cannot be converted by wget. In my case, Wordpress rewrites certain URLs, which seems to confuse wget and show up as absolute URLs (`http://...`) in the output.

As a hacky work-around, I used Wordpress filters to make the app refer to relative URLs, and these are handled as expected by wget.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You should use `robots=off` params.